Boost compiles with GCC but not MinGW (using CMake)
So I have a project in C++ to generate some batch files from JSON files, which I build with CMake. I am on Windows, but using WSL2 to do everything in Linux. I've developed everything and built it with GCC, but now that I am testing MinGW, I am getting issues with MinGW finding the Boost Libraries. Here's the CMake config:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# Set some basic project attributes
project (myproject
    VERSION 1.0
    DESCRIPTION "bla bla bla")

# C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

# Add definitions here
# add_definitions(-D....)

# Different versions for Debug and Release
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG_INIT "-Wall -g3 -O0")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE_INIT "-Wall -O3 -s -pipe")

# Astyle Option in make
add_custom_target (astyle
    COMMAND
    COMMAND astyle -r ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.h ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp --exclude=build
    VERBATIM
)

# Find Doxygen to create documentation
FIND_PACKAGE(Doxygen)

# In case Doxygen is found create a target to create the documentation
if (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
    # Set the input and output file paths
    set(DOXYGEN_IN ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Doxyfile)
    set(DOXYGEN_OUT ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Doxyfile.doxygen)

    # request to configure the file
    configure_file(${DOXYGEN_IN} ${DOXYGEN_OUT} @ONLY)
    message("Starting doxygen build process")

    # Add a target to create the documentation
    add_custom_target(doc_doxygen # ALL -> In case of automatic build always build all the documentation
        COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${DOXYGEN_OUT}
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
        COMMENT "Create doxygen documentation"
        VERBATIM )
else (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
  message("Doxygen not found, not building documentation")
endif (DOXYGEN_FOUND)

# Export file for CMake configuration
configure_file(config.h.in ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/config.h)

# Find Boost
find_package(Boost REQUIRED log_setup log thread system filesystem chrono)

# If installed jsoncpp will be found automatically on UNIX Systems
IF (MINGW)
    # Including JSON-CPP on Windows Systems
    include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/jsoncpp/include)
    link_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/jsoncpp/lib)
ENDIF ()

# Includes
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/logging/include)
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/buffer/include)
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/options/include)
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/secFunctions/include)

# Path for final executable (has to be defined before subdirectories)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

# Subdirectory
add_subdirectory(logging)
add_subdirectory(buffer)
add_subdirectory(options)
add_subdirectory(secFunctions)

# Add libraries
IF (MINGW)
   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} jsoncpp wsock32 ws2_32)
ELSE (MINGW)
   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} jsoncpp)
ENDIF ()

Everything works fine when building with GCC 11.4, however when I use MinGW (GCC 10), it all falls apart. I get the following error messages:
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
[cmake]   Could NOT find Boost (missing: log_setup log thread system filesystem
[cmake]   chrono) (found version "1.74.0")
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
[cmake]   /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2360 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
[cmake]   CMakeLists.txt:54 (find_package)

I've tried rewriting the CMake Config for MinGW which then "works" when compiling, but when it comes to building the project, it doesn't recognize Boost at all. What am I doing wrong?

Pass additional option -DBoost_DEBUG=ON. That way CMake will print which exact Boost libraries it searches and where. Compare that libraries with ones which you actually have.

I found out that MinGW doesn't have the folder with cmake and all the Boost Libraries. I tried first linking Boost_ROOT to the GCC folder with it. Then I tried copying over all the files to the MinGW folder. Both worked for a moment, but as soon as I restarted WSL both stopped working... Any clue why?

Just curious. Why do you use WSL in the first place?
Isn't it easier to use MSYS2 shell instead and its package manager pacman to install MinGW-w64 GCC and dependencies like Boost?

@BrechtSanders I'm using it because I generally prefer the Linux environment for programming plus because it is a requirement for it to be able to be built w/ Ubuntu. So I'd like to have MinGW working on Ubuntu as well.

I forgot to notify you in my last comment, but @Tsyvarev , do you know why this would be the case?

As far as I know, native Linux libraries (as you have under WSL) are not compatible with MinGW ones. In any case, output of Boost_DEBUG option should give some clue. You didn't show that output, so it is difficult to guess what is going wrong. BTW, even without @<name> I has notified about your first comment, since I was the author of the comment which precedes it.

@Tsyvarev thanks for the info, I didn't know that you still get notified, I'm pretty new to interacting on StackOverflow. Anyways, I have now tried to do it natively under Windows using MSYS2 for MinGW and the libraries and now it works. I haven't found any Ubuntu libraries for MinGW-Boost, -CMake, ... so I am gonna leave it at that. I attempted to build it in Arch, since Arch has MinGW-Boost, etc. but there I have the issue that it doesn't recognize the JSONCPP library, so I guess this is the end? I am satisfied with it building on Ubuntu and Windows with GCC and MinGW, thank you for the help
